# What's the Input key of MapReduce by default?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using `MpaReduce` based on `hadoop 2.6.0`,and I want to skip the first six lines of my data file, so I use

```
if(key.get()<6) 
   return ; 
else 
   {do ....}
```

in my `map() function`.

But it was not right. I find that the `input key` of `map()` is not the `offset`  of file line. The key is the sum of the length of every line. Why? It doesn't look like the words in many books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you look at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.7/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java#LineRecordReader.0pos), it is the actual byte offset of the file and not the line.

If you want to skip the first n lines of your file, you probably have to write your own input format / record reader, or make sure that you keep a line counter in the mapper logic ala:

```
 int lines = 0;
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, ...) {
   if(++lines < 6) { return; }

 }
```

This obviously doesn't work if you split the text file (so having > 1 mapper). So writing a dedicated `InputFormat` is the cleanest way to solve this problem.

Another trick would be to measure how many bytes the first n lines are in that specific file and then just skipping this amount of bytes at the start.